# What's the difference between ( = Vector3.zero ) and ( .Equals(Vector3.zero) )?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject tree;
```

What's the difference between:

```
tree.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```

and

```
tree.transform.localPosition.Equals(Vector3.zero);
```

Can anyone please explain by c# ex?

Comment: first is assignment and second is comparison

Comment: second returns a `bool`, first one sets your tree to a new position ...

Comment: @viveknuna can you give me an example of use in c# ?      when i use it i did not get an error but the game ignored the code line

Comment: @RYNEXRynex an example for what? Could you rather please add the code you are currently using which is not working as expected? ... in general maybe you should first look into some basic c# beginner tutorials instead of directly jumping into development for Unity?

Comment: @RYNEXRynex simplest example I have for you `string str = "vivek";
bool flag = str.Equals("vivek") ? true : false;`

Comment: @viveknuna strange example though ^^ wouldn't it be simply `bool flag = str.Equals("vivek");` ;)

Comment: @derHugo haha agreed :)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> tree.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
> ```

This **assigns** a new position to your `tree` object. In this case setting it to the parent position or World `0,0,0` if it has none.

---

> ```
> tree.transform.localPosition.Equals(Vector3.zero);
> ```

This **returns** a `bool` checking whether you are dealing with the exactly same position. See [`Vector3.Equals`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Equals.html).

It makes no sense as a standalone code line since you are not using the return value for anything and it will not change anything. This is why there is a warning but no game breaking exceptions .. the line is just completely useless.

You would want to either use the return value or assign it to something in order to use it later like

```
bool isAtOrigin = tree.transform.position.Equals(Vector3.zero);
```

and then you **might** want to use it for checking the condition like e.g.

```
if(tree.transform.position.Equals(Vector3.zero))
{
    // then do something
}
```

However, usually this is not recommended though due to floating point precision .. In particular for moving objects you would usually rather go for

```
if(tree.transform.position == Vector3.zero)
{
    // then do something
}
```

where [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses a approximated precision of `0.00001`

---

Without offend but this is a quite basic question and you should rather take a step back and get into some `c#` basics first before jumping into Unity development ;)

Comment: Oo right, i forgot that i need to set var for return , thx

Answer (score 0):

as someone answered

Equals proves for identity, that means the object are EXACT the same. You could override Equals, in this case you can check their properties. (in case of object.Equals, you prove for identity).
Using "=" you are assigning a value to it.

The is expression is true if expr isn't null, and any of the following is true: (SRC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

expr is an instance of the same type as type.

expr is an instance of a type that derives from type. In other words, the result of expr can be upcast to an instance of type.

expr has a compile-time type that is a base class of type, and expr has a runtime type that is type or is derived from type. The compile-time type of a variable is the variable's type as defined in its declaration. The runtime type of a variable is the type of the instance that is assigned to that variable.

expr is an instance of a type that implements the type interface.
Here you can find how to override Equals: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Here some examples:

```
    public class Word
{
    public string Name,Planet;

    public Word(string name, string planet)
    {
        Name = name;
        Planet = planet;
    }

    //Euqals is no overriden
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }


    public class OtherClass
    {
        public OtherClass()
        {
            Word word = new Word("word","erth");
            Word otherWord = new Word("word","moon");
            string a = null;

            var r = a == null; //true
            var r2 = object.Equals(a, null);//true      
            var r3 = word.Name is string; //true
            var r4 = word.Name is Word; //false
            var r5 = word.Equals(otherWord); //false
        }
    }
```

In case you override equals in your class:

```
public class Word
{
    public string Name;

    public Word(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    //Override Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if ((obj == null) || !this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Word thisWord = (Word) obj;
            return (Name == thisWord.Name) /* && (Other properties)*/;
        }
    }


    public class OtherClass
    {
        public OtherClass()
        {
            Word word = new Word("word","erth");
            Word otherWord = new Word("word","moon");
            string a = null;

            var r = a == null; //true
            var r2 = object.Equals(a, null);//true      
            var r3 = word.Equals(otherWord); //true
        }
    }
```

thanks!!

Comment: `Vector3` already **HAS** a custom [`Equals`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/016297e35ce1bf35a2c411f87fe0d6362cad54c3/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L242) implementation ;)

Comment: All your points starting with `The is expression is true if ....` actually fully depend on the implementation of `Equals` .. they are good practice but in no way given ... per default this only ever checks for **reference equality** unless you implement `Equals` yourself